# Simple mechanics problem about drag forces

Tags: homework-and-exercises, simulations, projectile, computational-physics, drag

I am supposed to be finding the expressing for velocity as a function of position, $v(x)$, of a car that is holding its brakes. I am given that the car is subject to the drag forces of quadratic air resistance ($cv^2$), and friction with the pavement ($\mu m g$).

I start by defining the function $\dfrac{dv}{dt}$:

$F_{net} = -\mu mg - cv^2$

$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = a = \dfrac{F_{net}}{m} = -\mu g - \dfrac{c}{m}v^2 $

and now cast it into the form $dv/dx$ via the chain rule:

$\dfrac{dv}{dt} = \dfrac{dv}{dx}\dfrac{dx}{dt} = v\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

So then

$\dfrac{dv}{dx} = \dfrac{\dfrac{dv}{dt}}{v} = -\dfrac{\mu g}{v} - \dfrac{c}{m}v$

but when I plot the vector field of $\dfrac{dv}{dx}$ on $x$-$v$ axes, it looks nonsensical.

[image: vector field]

It doesn't make sense to me that the velocity should decrease faster and faster. It seems that it should rather have a horizontal asymptote at zero. Have I done something wrong in deriving my ODE's?

Comment: That's the thing about sliding friction, it becomes false once you cross $v=0$.  Because the friction is always directed __against__ the motion, there is an implicit term $sgn(v)$ involved, thus you have to mirror the velocity field for negative velocities and directly at $v=0$ you have a single line with vanishing vectors.

Comment: @Bort But I never even evaluate the vector field at any negative values. the $v$ points have range [0.01, 35].

Comment: My comment was in the direction that the problem you are seeing is not a problem, because you will not cross $v=0$. The other point is the length. For that keep in mind, that you move to the right in time with velocity $v$. Everything is fine and only kind of counterintuitive due to the means of presentation.

Answer (score 0):

Your differential equation looks fine.

To simplify the solution I put in some numbers for your constants.

I have not stated the solutions for $v$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}$ as I think that is for you to do.

Plotting $v$ against $x$ and $\frac{dv}{dx}$ against $x$ with my constants gives :

[image]

The imaginary parts are to be ignored as they occur after the speed becomes zero.

I think that the graph you need to draw should follow the left hand graph and after an initial increase in the gradient $\frac{dv}{dx}$ there is a very rapid decrease as the car come to a halt.